# Getting value of custom attribute from selected option to a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a country select with the option tag containing a custom attribute : name.

I want to assign the value of this attribute to a javascript variable which would then be appended to a link and sent forward.

But with the current code I am unable to set the value of the variable.

Following is the line of code that I have currently:

```
var code = $("#countrySelect option:selected", this).attr("name");

<select name="CountrySelector" id="countrySelect">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="355" name="al">Albania</option>
    <option value="213" name="dz">Algeria</option>
</select>
```

I need to assign the value of the custom attribute "name" to the variable code.

Can anyone please help me in resolving this?

Comment: include HTML as well. Also, what is `this`? are you trying to get it in change event?

Comment: since you are using an ID in your selector, there should only be one of it on the page, so restricting the select to `this` (whatever that is) is not needed. The real cause of your problem is that the element in question is not in `this`.

Comment: Some elements implement a `name` attribute. If you're going to add a custom attribute to an element, you should be using `data-*`. jQuery even has a `.data(...)` function to grab that value - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `this` from your code:

```
 $("#countrySelect option:selected").attr("name");
```

But you should really be using `data-*` attributes to store random data in your HTML elements. jQuery makes them easy to use them: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I got the desired result.